# Encode Strings in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, encode, arabic

I want to run my code on terminal but it shows me this error :

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd8' in file streaming.py on line
>   72, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/
>   for detail

I tried to encode the Arabic string using this :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

st = 'المملكة العربية السعودية'.encode('utf-8')
```

It's very important for me to run it on the terminal so I can't use IDLE.

Comment: I don't think you need to use `.encode` if you specify the encoding of the whole file.

Comment: You do (well, *should*) however have to use a `unicode` literal.

Comment: As in `u"المملكة العربية السعودية"`

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use python 2? Python 3 has far superior support for international character sets.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is since you are directly pasting your characters in to a python file, the interpreter (Python 2) attempts to read them as ASCII (even before you encode, it needs to define the literal), which is illegal. What you want is a unicode literal if pasting non-ASCII bytes:

```
x=u'المملكة العربية السعودية' #Or whatever the corresponding bytes are
print x.encode('utf-8')
```

You can also try to set the entire source file to be read as `utf-8`:

```
#/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and don't forget to make it run-able, and lastly, you can import the future from Python 3:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literal
```

at the top of the file, so string literals by default are `utf-8`. Note that `\xd8` appears as `phi` in my terminal, so make sure the encoding is correct.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work :( , is it because I'm running it on terminal ?

Comment: @RubaSuliman what specifically didn't work? If you pasted Arabic to the terminal and the font didn't exist, then yes, it could cause trouble. You can use the hex values to be on the safe side (like `\xd8`), then it should at least run.